# C# SHA512 Memory Issue

Tags: c#, memory-management, cryptography

I need an implementation of PBKDF2 in C#. There is already a class `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, but it uses SHA1, and I need SHA512. The problem that I faced with during implementation is intensive allocation of memory after each hash computing iteration. The proposed solution is to change a little bit `SHA512Managed` class implementation using disassembler. The problem is in `EndHash` method: every iteration it creates two new arrays. My solution is below. What do you think about it? May be there are some security considerations that I don't know?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace HashImprovement
{
    public class CustomSHA512Managed : SHA512Managed
    {
        private bool disposed;
        private ulong count;
        private readonly ulong[] stateSHA512;
        private readonly byte[] resultBlock = new byte[64];
        private byte[] partIn;

        public CustomSHA512Managed()
        {
            stateSHA512 = (ulong[]) typeof (SHA512Managed)
                .GetField("_stateSHA512", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(this);
        }

        public new byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer)
        {
            if (disposed)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(null);
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            count = (ulong) buffer.Length;
            HashCore(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            HashValue = HashFinal();
            Initialize();
            return HashValue;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            disposed = true;
        }

        [SecuritySafeCritical]
        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
        protected override byte[] HashFinal()
        {
            return EndHash();
        }

        [SecurityCritical]
        private byte[] EndHash()
        {
            Array.Clear(resultBlock, 0, resultBlock.Length);
            var length = 128 - (int) ((long) count & sbyte.MaxValue);
            if (length <= 16)
                length += 128;
            SetPartIn(length);
            HashCore(partIn, 0, partIn.Length);
            QuadWordToBigEndian(resultBlock, stateSHA512, 8);
            HashValue = resultBlock;
            return resultBlock;
        }

        [SecurityCritical]
        private void SetPartIn(int length)
        {
            if (partIn != null && length == partIn.Length)
                return;

            partIn = new byte[length];
            unchecked
            {
                partIn[0] = (byte)sbyte.MinValue;
            }
            var num = count * 8UL;
            partIn[length - 8] = (byte)(num >> 56 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 7] = (byte)(num >> 48 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 6] = (byte)(num >> 40 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 5] = (byte)(num >> 32 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 4] = (byte)(num >> 24 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 3] = (byte)(num >> 16 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 2] = (byte)(num >> 8 & byte.MaxValue);
            partIn[length - 1] = (byte)(num & byte.MaxValue);
        }

        private static void QuadWordToBigEndian(byte[] block, ulong[] x, int digits)
        {
            var index1 = 0;
            var index2 = 0;
            while (index1 < digits)
            {
                block[index2] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 56 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 1] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 48 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 2] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 40 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 3] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 32 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 4] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 24 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 5] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 16 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 6] = (byte) (x[index1] >> 8 & byte.MaxValue);
                block[index2 + 7] = (byte) (x[index1] & byte.MaxValue);
                ++index1;
                index2 += 8;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, there is no need to disassemble BCL libraries anymore, [their code is public](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha512managed.cs).

Answer (score 4):

Concerning the design: It's a hack.

- It uses private reflection, so Microsoft can change `SHA512Managed` whenever they feel like it, breaking your code. It also might not work on mono.
- Returning the same array each time violates the contract of the base class. Not a big issue as long as the class is internal.

  Consider using a different method, something like `void GetHash(byte[] buffer)` instead.
- Are you sure the cost of allocating the array matters?

  Each SHA-512 compression (and with typical use in PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-2 you'll have two of them per hash) costs about 2000 CPU cycles. In my micro-benchmarks the cost of allocating and collecting small short lived objects is below 100 CPU cycles.

Concerning the code itself:

- You write:

  ```
  var length = 128 - (int) ((long) count & sbyte.MaxValue)
  ```

  and

  ```
  partIn[0] = (byte)sbyte.MinValue;
  ```

  This is unintuitive. While both the block size of SHA-512 and `sbyte.MaxValue + 1` happen to be 128, they're completely unrelated.

  Define a constant `const int BlockSize = 128` and replace this with:

  ```
  var length = BlockSize - (int)(count & (BlockSize-1));
  ```
- You write:

  ```
  partIn[length - 8] = (byte)(num >> 56 & byte.MaxValue);
  ```

  I'd simply use an unchecked context and eliminate the `& byte.MaxValue` part.

Alternative approaches:

1. Use native interop to call a high performance native library.

   While `SHA512CSP` and `SHA512Cng` have a high per-call overhead which makes them slower than `SHA512Managed`, this isn't true for native interop in general. In a different project I called OpenSSL's MD5 from C#, which was much faster than any implementation built into .NET.
2. Use an existing managed implementation of PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512. I think BouncyCastle includes it.
3. Start with an open source implementation of SHA-512 and tweak it to your needs.

   - Make sure to save the state of SHA-512 after the first block, this speeds up HMAC by a factor 2.
   - Most of the time the output of SHA-512 is used as the input for the next iteration. No need to convert between bytes and longs on each iteration.
   - Apart from the first iteration the message length is fixed (512 bits), so you can hardcode the padding.
   - A bit of advertisement:

     I wrote a public domain implementation of SHA-512 which is about 30% faster than `Sha512Managed`, when including the above optimizations you should be able to be at least 2.6 times as fast as an implementation that uses the built in HMAC-SHA-512 as a blackbox.

     [Compression function](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Chaos.NaCl/blob/2c861348dc45369508e718aa08611c53b53553db/Chaos.NaCl/Internal/Sha512Internal.cs) and [the hash including padding](https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Chaos.NaCl/blob/2c861348dc45369508e718aa08611c53b53553db/Chaos.NaCl/Sha512.cs).

Comment: Thanks! Your implementation is really faster. And as regards memory consumption: do you think it could be neglected in high loaded systems?